# VBA Excel: Module visible in the project explorer, but not the code window

Tags: excel, vba

I'm on Windows 10, Excel 2016.

I have a project I've been working on for quite a while. It consists of a userform and two modules. Now, after a week or so, I've opened the Excel file containing the code again. I see the modules and userform in the project explorer; I can view the code of the userform and one of the modules. However, the other module doesn't show me the code window. I double click on it and it doesn't appear.

When double clicking on the module, the module name (under module properties, below the project explorer) does change. However, if from there I try to change the name of either module, I get the error message "Can't perform requested operation". Changing the userform's name works.

Any idea what I can do about this?

Comment: At the top of the code window (in the menu bar)... click on `Window...` and then `Cascade` to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Sounds like your file is corrupt.  You'll probably have to restore from a backup ( you _do_ have a backup,  right?)

Comment: Following up on Chris' thought: You can try File->Export to see if the VBA Editor can create *.bas files from the modules. If it can, then these can be imported into a new project (the code won't be lost)...

Comment: Another thing you can try is to save the document under a new name with Save As. I ran into a simiiliar issue in Visio although only UFs where affected there.

Comment: @braX That solved it, thank you. I'm glad it was this easy and I don't have to use a backup

Comment: I had the same issue. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69036949/10022961) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top of the code window (in the menu bar)... click on `Window...` and then `Cascade`

the child window is most likely just moved off the edge of the screen and that should reset it.

Answer (score 9):

If someone comes across the same issue but the suggested solution of cascading the code windows doesn't do the trick, this approach has helped me numerous times:

Under Excel Options -> Trust Centre -> Trust Centre Settings

- -> External Content: set all radio buttons to disable
- -> Macro Settings: disable VBA macros without notification, untick the checkboxes
- -> ActiveX Settings: disable all controls without notification
- -> Add-ins: tick the checkbox Disable all Add-ins
- -> Trusted Add-in Catalogs: tick the checkbox Don't allow any web add-ins to start
- -> Trusted Documents: tick the checkbox Disable Trusted Documents
- -> Trusted Locations: tick the checkbox Disable all Trusted Locations

Restart Excel, open the file that plays up, open VBA and in the menu bar click on Debug -> Compile VBAProject, then save your file, and under Excel Options -> Trust Centre reset all changed settings, and restart Excel.

Comment: Thanks I was scared to death after seeing the corrupted file notification... Though I am using OneDrive and backups are available but I do not really want to write things all over again. I have no idea why your solution works but it just did the trick. The code window is back online now!

Comment: Works Office 365 in Feb 2024 and fixed concurrent alarming set of symptoms including #NAME? errors on UDFs, not-selecting-next-cell on <Enter> key, ...