# Written VBA coding not showing in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, code-editor

All of a sudden i am now unable to view VBA codes i have written in Outlook. Macro security also enabled for all macros. Anyone know how this can be resolved and me to see all coding again?

[VBA code not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPZSu.png)

Expecting to view VBA codes i have written once click on a module. I can view forms created, But cannot view any of codes written

Comment: Previously  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57454153/vba-excel-module-visible-in-the-project-explorer-but-not-the-code-window

Answer (score 0):

In the menu click on `Window` and then `Cascade` to see code editor windows displayed. Also you may double click on the module to get it displayed.